# Poker Game: Player and computer generating same hand

Tags: c#

I'm creating a Pokergame where the player versus a computer.
I'm running into an issue though where:

**the player and computer are generating the same hand/cards.**

I'm assuming it's either a sorting issue or shuffling issue but can't seem to find where the problem is. Can anyone help?

Example of what I mean

[image]

Deal Class:

```
    namespace PROG120_FINALPROJECT
    {
    class Deal : DeckofCards
    {
        private Card[] PlayerHand;
        private Card[] ComputerHand;
        private Card[] SortPHand; //sorted player hand
        private Card[] SortCHand; // sorted computer hand


        public Deal()
        {
            PlayerHand = new Card[5];
            SortPHand = new Card[5];
            ComputerHand = new Card[5];
            SortCHand = new Card[5];
        }

        public void DealSetup()
        {
            SetDeck(); //create the deck of cards and shuffle them
            GetHand();
            sortCards();
            evaluateHands();
        }


        public void GetHand()
        {
            //5 cards for the player 
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                PlayerHand[i] = GetDeck[i];


            //5 cards for computer
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                ComputerHand[i] = GetDeck[i];
        }

        public void sortCards()
        {
            var seePlayer = from hand in PlayerHand
                              orderby hand.CardValue
                              select hand;

            var seeComputer = from hand in ComputerHand
                                orderby hand.CardValue
                                select hand;

            var index = 0;
            foreach (var element in seePlayer.ToList())
            {
                SortPHand[index] = element;
                index++;
            }

            index = 0;
            foreach (var element in seeComputer.ToList())
            {
                SortCHand[index] = element;
                index++;
            }
        }
        public void evaluateHands()
        {
            //create player's computer's evaluation objects (passing Sorted hand to constructor)
            HandEvaluator playerHandEvaluator = new HandEvaluator(SortPHand);
            HandEvaluator computerHandEvaluator = new HandEvaluator(SortCHand);

            //get the player's and computer's handj
            Hand playerHand = playerHandEvaluator.EvaluateHand();
            Hand computerHand = computerHandEvaluator.EvaluateHand();

            //display each hand
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nPlayer's Hand: " + playerHand);
            foreach (var card in PlayerHand)
            {
                Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
                Console.Write(" of ");
                Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nComputer's Hand: " + computerHand);

            foreach (var card in PlayerHand)
            {
                Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
                Console.Write(" of ");
                Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            //evaluate hands
            if (playerHand > computerHand)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
            }
            else if (playerHand < computerHand)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
            }
            else //if the hands are the same, evaluate the values
            {
                //first evaluate who has higher value of hand
                if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total > computerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total)
                    Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
                else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total < computerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total)
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
                //if both hanve the same poker hand 
                // player with the next higher card wins
                else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard > computerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard)
                    Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
                else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard < computerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard)
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Draw, no one wins!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class DeckofCards:

```
    namespace PROG120_FINALPROJECT
    {
        //START CLASS DoC
        class DeckofCards : Card
    {
        int AllCards = 52; //52 cards in a deck
        private Card[] Deck; //array of playing cards

        public DeckofCards()
        {
            Deck = new Card[AllCards];
        }

        public Card[] GetDeck //grab current deck
        {
            get
            { return Deck; }
        }

        public void SetDeck()
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (SUIT s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SUIT)))
            {
                foreach (VALUE v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(VALUE)))
                {
                    Deck[i] = new Card { CardSuit = s, CardValue = v };
                    i++;
                }
            }
            Shuffle();
        }

        //shuffle deck
        public void Shuffle()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Card temp;

            //run shuffle 100 times
            for (int ShuffleAmount = 0; ShuffleAmount < 100; ShuffleAmount++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < AllCards; i++)
                {
                    //swap cards
                    int SecondCardIndex = rand.Next(13);
                    temp = Deck[i];
                    Deck[i] = Deck[SecondCardIndex];
                    Deck[SecondCardIndex] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        //END of CLASS DoC
    }
}
```

I don't think you'll need these but just in case here are my other classes-

HandEval:

```
    namespace PROG120_FINALPROJECT
    {
        public enum Hand
        {
        Nothing,
        OnePair, //Jacks or Better
        TwoPairs,
        ToK, //Three of a kind
        Str, //straight
        Flush,
        StrFlush, //straight flush
        FullH, // Full House 
        FoK, // Four of a  Kind 
        Royal, //Royal Flush                 
    }

    public struct HandValue
    {
        public int Total
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int HighCard
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class HandEvaluator : Card
    {
        private int SpadeSum;
        private int HeartSum;
        private int DiamondSum;
        private int ClubSum;
        private Card[] cards;
        private HandValue HV; //Hand Value

        public HandEvaluator(Card[] SortedHand)
        {
            SpadeSum = 0;
            HeartSum = 0;
            DiamondSum = 0;
            ClubSum = 0;
            cards = new Card[5];
            cards = SortedHand;
            HV = new HandValue();
        }

        public HandValue HVs
        {
            get
            { return HV; }
            set
            { HV = value; }
        }

        public Card [] Cards
        {
            get
            { return cards; }
            set
            {
                cards[0] = value[0];
                cards[1] = value[1];
                cards[2] = value[2];
                cards[3] = value[3];
                cards[4] = value[4];                               
            }
        }

        public Hand EvaluateHand()
        {
            //gets number of each suit on hand
            getNumberofSuit();
            if (Royal())
                return Hand.Royal;
            else if (FoK())
                return Hand.FoK;
            else if (FullH())
                return Hand.FullH;
            else if (StrFlush())
                return Hand.StrFlush;
            else if (Flush())
                return Hand.Flush;
            else if (Str())
                return Hand.Str;
            else if (ToK())
                return Hand.ToK;
            else if (TwoPairs())
                return Hand.TwoPairs;
            else if (OnePair())
                return Hand.OnePair;

            //if hand is nothing, player with highest card wins
            HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
            return Hand.Nothing;            
        }

        private void getNumberofSuit()
        {
            foreach (var element in Cards)
            {
                if (element.CardSuit == Card.SUIT.SPADE)
                    SpadeSum++;
                else if (element.CardSuit == Card.SUIT.HEART)
                    HeartSum++;
                else if (element.CardSuit == Card.SUIT.DIAMOND)
                    DiamondSum++;
                else if (element.CardSuit == Card.SUIT.CLUB)
                    ClubSum++;
            }
        }

        private bool Royal()
        {
            // a straight flush including ace, king, queen, jack, and ten all in the same suit.
            //all suits are same & 5 consecutive values
            if (SpadeSum == 5 || HeartSum == 5 || DiamondSum == 5 || ClubSum == 5 &&
                 cards[0].CardValue + 1 == cards[1].CardValue &&
                 cards[1].CardValue + 1 == cards[2].CardValue &&
                 cards[2].CardValue + 1 == cards[3].CardValue &&
                 cards[3].CardValue + 1 == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool FoK()
        {
            //if the first 4 cards, add values of the four cards and last card is the highest
            if (cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue && cards[0].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue && cards[0].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[1].CardValue * 4;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[1].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue && cards[1].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue && cards[1].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[1].CardValue * 4;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[0].CardValue;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool FullH()
        {
            //the first three cards and last two cards are of the same value
            //first two cards, and last three cards are of the same value
            if ((cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue && cards[0].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue && cards[3].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue) ||
                (cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue && cards[2].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue && cards[2].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue))
            {
                HV.Total = (int)(cards[0].CardValue) + (int)(cards[1].CardValue) + (int)(cards[2].CardValue) +
                    (int)(cards[3].CardValue) + (int)(cards[4].CardValue);
                return true;
            }

            return false;           
        }

        private bool StrFlush()
        { 
            //all suits are same & 5 consecutive values
            if (SpadeSum == 5 || HeartSum == 5 || DiamondSum == 5 || ClubSum == 5 &&
                 cards[0].FaceValue + 1 == cards[1].FaceValue &&
                 cards[1].FaceValue + 1 == cards[2].FaceValue &&
                 cards[2].FaceValue + 1 == cards[3].FaceValue &&
                 cards[3].FaceValue + 1 == cards[4].FaceValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool Flush()
        {
            //if all suits are the same
            if (SpadeSum == 5 || HeartSum == 5 || DiamondSum == 5 || ClubSum == 5)
            {
                //if tie flush player with higher cards win
                //whomever has last card has highest value, has automatically  all the cards total higher
                HV.Total = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool Str()
        {
            //if 5 consecutive value
            if (cards[0].CardValue + 1 == cards[1].CardValue &&
                cards[1].CardValue + 1 == cards[2].CardValue &&
                cards[2].CardValue + 1 == cards[3].CardValue &&
                cards[3].CardValue + 1 == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                //player with highest value of the last card wins
                HV.Total = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private bool ToK()
        {
            //if the 1,2,3 cards are the same OR
            //2,3,4 cards are the same OR
            //3,4,5 cards are the same
            //3rds card will always be a part of Three of A Kind

            if ((cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue && cards[0].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue) ||
            (cards[1].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue && cards[1].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue))
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[2].CardValue * 3;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[2].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue && cards[2].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[2].CardValue * 3;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[1].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool TwoPairs()
        {
            //if 1,2 and 3,4
            //if 1.2 and 4,5
            //if 2.3 and 4,5
            //with two pairs, the 2nd card will always be a part of one pair 
            //and 4th card will always be a part of second pair
            if (cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue && cards[2].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = ((int)cards[1].CardValue * 2) + ((int)cards[3].CardValue * 2);
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue && cards[3].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = ((int)cards[1].CardValue * 2) + ((int)cards[3].CardValue * 2);
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[2].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[1].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue && cards[3].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = ((int)cards[1].CardValue * 2) + ((int)cards[3].CardValue * 2);
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[0].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool OnePair()
        {
            //if 1,2 -> 5th card has the highest value
            //2.3
            //3,4
            //4,5 -> card #3 has the highest value
            if (cards[0].CardValue == cards[1].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[0].CardValue * 2;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[1].CardValue == cards[2].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[1].CardValue * 2;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[2].CardValue == cards[3].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[2].CardValue * 2;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
                return true;
            }
            else if (cards[3].CardValue == cards[4].CardValue)
            {
                HV.Total = (int)cards[3].CardValue * 2;
                HV.HighCard = (int)cards[2].CardValue;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }


    }

        //END OF NAMESPACE
}
```

Cards Class:

```
    namespace PROG120_FINALPROJECT
    {
            //START CLASS CARD
        class Card
    {
        // Establishes suits
        public enum SUIT
        {
            SPADE,
            HEART,
            DIAMOND,
            CLUB
        }

        // Gives Cards a numeric vakue i.e. NINE of hearts
        public enum VALUE
        {
            TWO = 1, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
            SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN,
            JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
        }

        // just the face cards
        public enum FACE
        {
            JACK,
            QUEEN,
            KING,
            ACE
        }

        //Properties
        public SUIT CardSuit
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public VALUE CardValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public FACE FaceValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


    //END CLASS CARDS
    }
}
```

Program class:

```
    namespace PROG120_FINALPROJECT
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Define
            Deal dc = new Deal();
            // write string repersentation 
           // enum


            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the amount you would like to bet 1-5");
            float bet = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (bet < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid bet amount");
            }
            else
            {
                dc.DealSetup();
            }


                if (bet > 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter higher bet amount");
            }
            else
            {
                dc.GetHand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more thing - when you say that Deck is a subclass of Card (`class DeckofCards : Card`), you're saying that a Deck is a specific type of Card. That's probably not what you want. A Deck has Cards, it is not a specific type of Card.

Comment: Use a Stack or Queue for the deck so that the cards get used up (just like a shoe).  The random generator ought be one object used over and over in the course of the game; a better shuffle would be the standard Fisher-Yates shuffle which moves each card once and once only.  Hand evaluation can be done much simpler with 3-4 linq statements

Comment: @Plutonix - The issue here isn't with the random number generator - that will be the next problem. The current issue is the code is referencing the same elements in the the same array when selecting the cards for both hands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public void GetHand()
{
    //5 cards for the player 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        PlayerHand[i] = GetDeck[i];


    //5 cards for computer
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        ComputerHand[i] = GetDeck[i];
}
```

Deck is an array; you are retrieving the first 5 elements of that array twice. You probably want a function more like "GetNextCard" and keep track of the index inside the Deck class as it's not something the dealer should care about. Or implement Deck as a stack rather than array and pop each card off.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed this almost immediately after I posted the question. One question I do have out of curiosity you might know the answer to, is there a way to just delete/remove the used elements out of the array?

Comment: An Array has a fixed size, so not really. If you want to stick with an Array, I would go with keeping track of the index of the next card to deal inside of Deck. The most natural way to handle the dealing part would be to use a [Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of an Array, but that may not be something you've covered. You still could create and shuffle as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Not only were you setting your cards from the same first five values of the same array, you were also outputing the player's hand twice, and not the computer hand.

```
        foreach (var card in PlayerHand)
        {
            Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
```

Next, had you fixed those two problems the line `Random rand = new Random();` may have caused you problems as you need to ensure you only have one `Random` instance for the entire application otherwise you can get repeated values.

I did have a go at fixing your code. I didn't clean it all up, but this now works:

```
void Main()
{
    //Define
    Deal dc = new Deal();
    // write string repersentation 
    // enum


    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the amount you would like to bet 1-5");
    float bet = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (bet < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid bet amount");
    }
    else
    {
        dc.DealSetup();
    }


    if (bet > 5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter higher bet amount");
    }
    else
    {
        //dc.GetHand();
    }
}

class Deal
{
    private DeckofCards Deck = new DeckofCards();

    private Card[] PlayerHand;
    private Card[] ComputerHand;
    private Card[] SortPHand; //sorted player hand
    private Card[] SortCHand; // sorted computer hand


    public Deal()
    {
        var selected = this.Deck.GetDeck.Take(10).Select((x, n) => new { x, n }).GroupBy(x => x.n % 2, x => x.x).ToArray();
        this.PlayerHand = selected[0].ToArray();
        this.ComputerHand = selected[1].ToArray();
    }

    public void DealSetup()
    {
        sortCards();
        evaluateHands();
    }

    public void sortCards()
    {
        this.SortPHand = this.PlayerHand.OrderBy(x => x.CardValue).ToArray();
        this.SortCHand = this.ComputerHand.OrderBy(x => x.CardValue).ToArray();
    }

    public void evaluateHands()
    {
        //create player's computer's evaluation objects (passing Sorted hand to constructor)
        HandEvaluator playerHandEvaluator = new HandEvaluator(SortPHand);
        HandEvaluator computerHandEvaluator = new HandEvaluator(SortCHand);

        //get the player's and computer's handj
        Hand playerHand = playerHandEvaluator.EvaluateHand();
        Hand computerHand = computerHandEvaluator.EvaluateHand();

        //display each hand
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nPlayer's Hand: " + playerHand);
        foreach (var card in PlayerHand)
        {
            Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nComputer's Hand: " + computerHand);

        foreach (var card in ComputerHand)
        {
            Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        //evaluate hands
        if (playerHand > computerHand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
        }
        else if (playerHand < computerHand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
        }
        else //if the hands are the same, evaluate the values
        {
            //first evaluate who has higher value of hand
            if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total > computerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total)
                Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
            else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total < computerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total)
                Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
            //if both hanve the same poker hand 
            // player with the next higher card wins
            else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard > computerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard)
                Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
            else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard < computerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard)
                Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Draw, no one wins!");
        }
    }
}

class DeckofCards
{
    private Card[] Deck;

    public DeckofCards()
    {
        var cards =
            from s in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.SUIT)).Cast<Card.SUIT>()
            from v in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Card.VALUE)).Cast<Card.VALUE>()
            select new Card { CardSuit = s, CardValue = v };
        this.Deck = cards.ToArray();
        this.Shuffle();
    }

    public Card[] GetDeck //grab current deck
    {
        get
        { return Deck; }
    }

    private Random rand = new Random();

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        this.Deck = this.Deck.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray();
    }
}


public enum Hand
{
    Nothing,
    OnePair, //Jacks or Better
    TwoPairs,
    ToK, //Three of a kind
    Str, //straight
    Flush,
    StrFlush, //straight flush
    FullH, // Full House 
    FoK, // Four of a  Kind 
    Royal, //Royal Flush                 
}

public struct HandValue
{
    public int Total
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int HighCard
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class HandEvaluator
{
    private Card[] cards;
    private HandValue HV; //Hand Value

    public HandEvaluator(Card[] SortedHand)
    {
        cards = SortedHand;
        HV = new HandValue();
    }

    public HandValue HVs { get { return HV; } set { HV = value; } }

    public Card[] Cards { get { return cards; } }

    public Hand EvaluateHand()
    {
        //gets number of each suit on hand
        if (Royal())
            return Hand.Royal;
        else if (FoK())
            return Hand.FoK;
        else if (FullH())
            return Hand.FullH;
        else if (StrFlush())
            return Hand.StrFlush;
        else if (Flush())
            return Hand.Flush;
        else if (Str())
            return Hand.Str;
        else if (ToK())
            return Hand.ToK;
        else if (TwoPairs())
            return Hand.TwoPairs;
        else if (OnePair())
            return Hand.OnePair;

        //if hand is nothing, player with highest card wins
        HV.HighCard = (int)cards[4].CardValue;
        return Hand.Nothing;
    }

    private bool Str()
    {
        var aceHigh = cards.Select(c => (int)c.CardValue).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
        var aceLow = aceHigh.Select(x => x == 14 ? 1 : x).ToArray();

        return new[] { aceHigh, aceLow }.Any(cs => cs.Skip(1).Zip(cs, (c1, c0) => c1 - c0).All(x => x == 1));
    }

    private bool Royal()
    {
        var firstIsTen = cards.Select(c => (int)c.CardValue).Min() == 10;
        return firstIsTen && this.StrFlush();
    }

    private bool FoK()
    {
        return cards.GroupBy(x => x.CardValue).Any(x => x.Count() == 4);
    }

    private bool FullH()
    {
        return cards.GroupBy(x => x.CardValue).Select(x => x.Count()).OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(new[] { 2, 3 });
    }

    private bool StrFlush()
    {
        return this.Str() & this.Flush();
    }

    private bool Flush()
    {
        return cards.Select(x => x.CardSuit).Distinct().Count() == 1;
    }

    private bool ToK()
    {
        return cards.GroupBy(x => x.CardValue).Any(x => x.Count() == 3);
    }

    private bool TwoPairs()
    {
        return cards.GroupBy(x => x.CardValue).Select(x => x.Count()).OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(new[] { 1, 2, 2 });
    }

    private bool OnePair()
    {
        return cards.GroupBy(x => x.CardValue).Select(x => x.Count()).OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(new[] { 1, 1, 1, 2 });
    }
}

class Card
{
    public enum SUIT
    {
        SPADE,
        HEART,
        DIAMOND,
        CLUB
    }

    public enum VALUE
    {
        TWO = 2, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
        SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN,
        JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
    }

    public SUIT CardSuit { get; set; }
    public VALUE CardValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsFace
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this.CardValue >= (int)VALUE.JACK;
        }
    }
}
```

You really had a lot of unnecessary class inheritance.

Comment: wow. This is super helpful, I'm pretty new to coding; it didn't even occur to me that 'group by' might be a thing (I'm somewhat familiar with this from SQL). Also thanks for the catch on the player hand I didn't even notice I put player hand twice.

Comment: After looking further at your code I noticed something what is 'cs' in the bool str?:                                                                                          private bool Str()
            {
                var aceHigh = cards.Select(c => (int)c.CardValue).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
                var aceLow = aceHigh.Select(x => x == 14 ? 1 : x).ToArray();

                return new[] { aceHigh, aceLow }.Any(cs => cs.Skip(1).Zip(cs, (c1, c0) => c1 - c0).All(x => x == 1));
            }

Comment: @ElizabethFuenzalida - That's part of the lambda expression for the `.Any()` method call. The `cs` is either the `aceHigh` or the `aceLow` array in this case. In this code it is trying to see if the card value of each card only ascends by one per each consecutive card. If they both don't then there is no straight.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got rid of my duplicates in my poker game.

```
    /* Loop through up to five times while taking out a random card,
       move into the variable temp. Check to see if the temp is not
       in play, then count it as in play, add the card to Cards array
       and then set the temp array as true (cards being used).  
       Finally return the Cards. Note: number corresponds to five (Cards). */
    public SuperCard[] GetCards(int number)
    {
        SuperCard[] Cards = new SuperCard[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            Cards[i] = GetOneCard();
        }
        return Cards; // Return all five cards in the Card array.
    }


    //==== Added (Get One Card From 52 and replace the lowest card) ====

    /*Loop through to get a random card that is not inplay. 
      Then take the lowest number card out and replace it with a random card.*/
      // Just returns one random card. 
    public SuperCard GetOneCard() // Passing in number(5 Cards).
    {
        // Loop through 0 - 52 and check if the card is in play. If not, then return the card. 
        int temp;
        do
        {
            temp = rnd.Next(0, 52); // Get a random number from 0 to 52.

        } while (this[temp].inplay); // Check to see if the random number is in play.

        // This checks to see if the cards are in play. 
        this[temp].inplay = true; // Set the card inplay equal to true (doesn't use it again).
        SuperCard oneCard = this[temp]; // Same typeof, return one card.
        return oneCard; // Returns the one card. 
    }
```